# How read data with special encoding from AWS S3 in R?

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I try to read data from AWS S3 which have French symbols

```
df <- s3read_using(FUN = read.csv2, object = "xxx.csv", bucket = bucket_name)
```

This gives me values like "Eug\x82nie".

Is it possible to read data in the correct Unicode format?

Or is possible to fix values then "Eug\x82nie" => "Eugénie"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to test the answer to your question, but you can pass additional arguments to FUN in `s3read_using` function. So it might help to read about encodings in `help("read.csv2")`. For me it usually worked well with French characters due to `en_US.UTF-8` locale.